# Enqueue and Dequeue Json data in node.js

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, deque

Is it possible to enqueue and dequeue json data from Queue  using amqplib in node.js?

I need to try that Publish json array in publisher side and same thing doing for dequeue in consumer side.

Tryied Code:
Json Array is:
"{\"OTPMessage\":\"sjdfw78we\",\"MobileNum\":\"9164425882\"}"

```
ch.consume(QueueName,function(message) {           
           var OTP, MobileNumber;
           var jsondata=message.content.toString();
           var dd=JSON.stringify(jsondata);
          console.log(dd);
      } ,{noAck: false});
```

Comment: Please check ,I edited my trial code.

Comment: If `jsondata` is a JSON string, you should use `JSON.parse(jsondata)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I got my answer and here is my working code.

```
 ch.consume(QueueName,function(message) { 
           var jsondata=message.content.toString();  
           var otp=JSON.parse(jsondata).OTPMessage;             
           SendEmail(message,otp);
       } ,{noAck: false});
```